# Mocking a Directive to Test a Component - Angular 8 with jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I tried to write a unit test for a component which has some services and directive. The Directive is used to render the content differentiated by logged in user and guest user.

The mocked directive with the default value of "false" for "appShowAuthed", the test case pass. But when I try to alter the value, it does not re render the view.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *appShowAuthed="true">
     <button  id="logout">Logout</button>
</ng-container>

 <ng-container *appShowAuthed="false">
   <button  id="login">Login</button>
</ng-container>
```

Spec File:

```
//Passing Case

  it('should show Login button and hide My Orders Button for not logged in user', async () => 
  {
    await fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#login'))).not.toBeNull();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout'))).toBeNull();
  });



//Failing Case

 it('should show Login button and hide My Orders Button for not logged in user', async () => 
    {
       const datastore = TestBed.get(DataStoreService);
       datastore.isAuthenticated = of(true);

       fixture.detectChanges();
       await fixture.whenStable();
       await fixture.whenRenderingDone();
       expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout'))).not.toBeNull();
       expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeNull();
    });
```

The error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined"

I have added the the project with minimal code to reproduce the issue in gitHub.

[Repo Link](https://github.com/sinthu225/unit-testing-ang-8)

Please suggest me a better way to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
 it('should show Login button and hide My Orders Button for not logged in user', inject(
    [DataStoreService],
    async (injectService: DataStoreService) => {
      fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);
      injectService.isAuthenticated.next(true);
      await fixture.whenStable();
      await fixture.whenRenderingDone();
      expect(
        fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout')),
      ).not.toBeNull();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#login'))).toBeNull();
    },
  ));
```